# Getting TeamCity to read my NUnit Test configuration file

Tags: .net, testing, nunit, teamcity

I have a project in VS 2010 using NUnit and C# to test my application. My project is called MyProjectTests and as per NUnit, I have a MyProjectTests.config file that has a connection string in it to my test database, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>

    <add key="defaultConnection" value="MyConnection"/>
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="My_Connection_String_Details" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But when I run my TeamCity NUnit tests, the connection string is Null. How do I make TeamCiry read my connection file? Is something else wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should name your settings file as App.config, put in the root of test project and include it. NUnit and TeamCity runners both will use settings from that app.config.